# Regexp - Get the first and last part

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is there a way to get the first and last part of the below lines?
I'm guessing that regexp is the way to go. Preferably with notepad++

This doesn't have to be super optimized or anything. Its something that will be executed manually occasionally and if it runs for several minutes, that's fine.

If it's a big problem of handling both the 'TimeingLog' and 'HandleArticleWarningOnOrder' lines in the same regexp I can run two different regexp and combine the result.

I have used this regexp to find the lines in the first place, they are from a much bigger list with lots of rows that im not interested in.
`^.{26}(HandleArticleWarningOnOrder ->  -1.*|Timinglog.*)`

Note that the lines can be longer or shorter than the below example

Input

```
2022-01-11 09:52:35.65 -> TimingLog -> 1: '69' -2: '434' -3: '434' -4: '434' -5: '509' -6: '509' -6.1: '509' -7: '588' -19: '588' -20: '588' -21: '5145' -22: '5202' -23: '5224' -24: '5233' -25: '5233'
2022-01-11 09:52:48.82 -> TimingLog -> 1: '47' -2: '213' -3: '213' -4: '213' -5: '269' -6: '269' -6.1: '269' -7: '298' -8: '298' -12: '380' -13: '380' -14: '6270' -15: '6328' -16: '6347' -17: '6356' -18: '6356'
2022-01-11 09:53:02.68 -> TimingLog -> 1: '23' -2: '54' -3: '54' -4: '54' -5: '65' -6: '65' -6.1: '65' -7: '76' -19: '76' -20: '76' -21: '4916' -22: '4982' -23: '5010' -24: '5015' -25: '5015'
2022-01-11 09:53:06.57 -> HandleArticleWarningOnOrder ->  -1: '160' -2: '223' -1: '223' -2: '285' -1: '285' -2: '671' -1: '671' -2: '816' -1: '816' -2: '970' -1: '970' -2: '1122' -3: '1122' -4: '1312' -5: '17766' -6: '17766'
2022-01-11 09:53:17.01 -> TimingLog -> 1: '140' -2: '527' -3: '527' -4: '527' -5: '671' -6: '671' -6.1: '671' -7: '737' -19: '737' -20: '737' -21: '5984' -22: '6163' -23: '6307' -24: '6339' -25: '6339'
2022-01-11 09:53:25.12 -> TimingLog -> 1: '25' -2: '85' -3: '85' -4: '85' -5: '108' -6: '108' -6.1: '108' -7: '117' -19: '117' -20: '117' -21: '7706' -22: '7880' -23: '8018' -24: '8110' -25: '8110'
2022-01-11 09:53:31.90 -> TimingLog -> 1: '51' -2: '210' -3: '210' -4: '210' -5: '269' -6: '269' -6.1: '269' -7: '324' -19: '324' -20: '324' -21: '6641' -22: '6675' -23: '6704' -24: '6711' -25: '6711'
2022-01-11 09:53:44.04 -> TimingLog -> 1: '27' -2: '121' -3: '121' -4: '121' -5: '202' -6: '202' -6.1: '202' -7: '215' -19: '215' -20: '215' -21: '6520' -22: '6566' -23: '6594' -24: '6604' -25: '6604'
2022-01-11 09:53:53.51 -> TimingLog -> 1: '72' -2: '275' -3: '275' -4: '275' -5: '302' -6: '302' -6.1: '302' -7: '327' -8: '327' -12: '413' -13: '413' -14: '7408' -15: '7571' -16: '7725' -17: '7731' -18: '7731'
2022-01-11 09:54:04.27 -> TimingLog -> 1: '22' -2: '72' -3: '72' -4: '72' -5: '86' -6: '86' -6.1: '86' -7: '105' -8: '105' -12: '147' -13: '147' -14: '5192' -15: '5223' -16: '5251' -17: '5269' -18: '5269'
2022-01-11 09:54:09.16 -> HandleArticleWarningOnOrder ->  -1: '91' -2: '188' -2.1: '188' -3: '188' -4: '351' -5: '18276' -6: '18276'
2022-01-11 09:54:12.80 -> TimingLog -> 1: '13' -2: '43' -3: '43' -4: '43' -5: '51' -6: '51' -6.1: '51' -7: '57' -8: '57' -12: '86' -13: '86' -14: '8024' -15: '8263' -16: '8430' -17: '8524' -18: '8524'
2022-01-11 09:54:21.30 -> TimingLog -> 1: '105' -2: '353' -3: '353' -4: '353' -5: '414' -6: '414' -6.1: '414' -7: '470' -8: '470' -12: '814' -13: '814' -14: '8172' -15: '8336' -16: '8449' -17: '8480' -18: '8480'
2022-01-11 09:54:34.02 -> HandleArticleWarningOnOrder ->  -1: '102' -2: '154' -2.1: '154' -3: '154' -4: '202' -5: '20106' -6: '20106'
...
```

Preferred Output

```
2022-01-11 09:52:35.65 -> TimingLog -> '5233'
2022-01-11 09:52:48.82 -> TimingLog -> '6356'
2022-01-11 09:53:02.68 -> TimingLog -> '5015'
2022-01-11 09:53:06.57 -> HandleArticleWarningOnOrder -> '17766'
2022-01-11 09:53:17.01 -> TimingLog -> '6339'
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replace with a branch reset group for your specific matches:

```
^(.{26})(?|(HandleArticleWarningOnOrder ->)\h{2,}-1\b|(TimingLog ->)).*('\d+')
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(.{26})` Capture **group 1**, match 26 characters (You could consider making this pattern a bit more specific)
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `(HandleArticleWarningOnOrder ->)\h{2,}-1\b` Capture the text in **group 2** followed by matching 2 or more spaces and `-1` and a word boundary to prevent a partial word match
  - `|` Or
  - `(TimingLog ->)` Capture **group 2**, match literally
- `)` Close branch reset group
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `('\d+')` Capture the last occurrence of 1+ digits between single quotes in **group 3**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKunMK/1)

In the replacement use capture group 1, 2 and 3 like `$1$2 $3`

[image]

Perhaps a more simpler patter using `\K` and a single capture group:

```
^.{26}(?:HandleArticleWarningOnOrder ->(?=\h{2,}-1\b)|TimingLog ->)\K.*('\d+')
```

In the replacement use  `$1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEo8hk/1)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for the replacement of the string.

```
^(.*->)( *(-)?\d*(\.)?\d*: ('\d{1,}\'))*$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jcjemU/1)

And replace with this ***$1$5***, capturing 1st and 5th group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short code for your given sample ...

Find: `^(\d.*->).*('\d+')`
Replace All: `$1$2`